# In Java, what is the simplest way to reverse the string output of this program?

Tags: java, arrays, string, netbeans

What I'm trying to do is progressively "reverse print" an alphabetical string from right to left like this:

```
A
BA
CBA
DCBA
etc...
```

Here is the foundation I'm working from which currently prints in normal order:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String output = "";
    for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <='Z'; alphabet++ )
        {
            output += alphabet;
            System.out.println(output);
        }
}
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: `"Sorry if this is a bad question but I'm a noob who's been searching for an answer to this problem for like an hour now."` -- don't post this type of information as it does not help us to better understand your question or your efforts. Instead much better would be to show the *concrete* results of what you did find in your searches as well as your best good faith attempt to solve this. Without this, your question is considered low-quality, may not be answered, and risks being closed.

Comment: `output += alphabet` (sort of) means `output = output + alphabet`. Knowing that, can you see how to make it do what you want?

Comment: @AndyTurner I assume then that I need something that prints the addition to the left of the current letter but I don't know how to "word" that exactly. What do you mean by "output += alphabet (sort of) means output = output + alphabet." by the way?

Comment: @minusxp [per the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), it actually means `output = (String) (output + alphabet)`. That it's got the extra cast is a largely irrelevant detail here, but that's what it is *actually* the same as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `output += alphabet;` to`output = alphabet + output;`
This does the job.